# Dll's, Message Boxes, and Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, dll, messagebox

Ok... I am working on a dll that manages some configured settings (I won't bore you with the details and reasoning here as that doesn't apply).  I have a class for referencing assemblies to use to interface with this system.  this class has a Load() method.  When there are read or validation errors, I currently have it showing a message box.  I didn't feel it should be the responsibility of the referencing assembly to manage this?  Or am I wrong?  Currently this is creating havoc with creating unit tests, so I'm considering adding a property to suppress messages, but still allow the exceptions to be thrown.  I read on one other SO posting where someone was recommended to use IoC and a dialog result helper class.  The illustration was with Constructor Injection... but that would again put that responsibility into the hands of the referencing assembly.  What's best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you're wrong - sorry. The DLL's responsibility is to notify of the errors, the calling code's responsibility is to determine what to do with that notification. If it's a GUI, then it can show a dialog box. If it's a unit test, it can test appropriately. If it's a website, it can write the notification out in HTML to the user. If it's a service of some sort, it can log it. And so on.

Comment: Well, that's why I was asking.  I've developed several little utility apps over the years as time has allowed, but nothing this big, so I was going with the concept of keeping this assembly contained.  But I see you're point.  So let me ask you then, what are your thoughts on using IoC for some kind of notification?  Try not to unless absolutely necessary?

Comment: Depends on the notification mechanisms available to the language you are using - you haven't specified. That's certainly an option, may not be the best one depending on the language.

Comment: I had considered creating my own Exception type so that when it's thrown I can control that much.

Comment: In that case, you might consider raising an event to notify the calling code. Or raising your own exception type. Depends on whether execution continues after an error or not amongst other things.

Comment: Ok... I think I'll use the custom exception type then and the calling code can use try/catch.  The event is not a bad thought either.  At first I was trying to avoid the try/catch from the calling code.

Comment: Curious... typically when developing a dll, do you handle most of the method calls with try/catch?  Or is there something more specific in terms of approaches that is typical?  I ask, because as I think about it, if one team of developers builds the dll, another may be using it... so what's their typical approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate to send messages to be handled elsewhere. I have made an example below using a unittest:

```
    public delegate void ErrorHandlingDelegate(Exception exception);  //The delegate 


    public class AsseblymRefClass //Your class doing the business logic 
    {
        public void DoStuff(ErrorHandlingDelegate errorHandling) //Passing the delegate as argument
        {
            try
            {
                //Do your stuff
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorHandling(ex); //Calling the delegate
            }
        }
    }


    //Another class that can handle the error through its method 'HandleErrorsFromOtherClass()'
    public class ErrorHandlingClass
    {
        public void HandleErrorsFromOtherClass(Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }

    }



    [Test]
    public void testmethod() //The test that creates your class, and a class for the errorhandling, and connects the two
    {
        ErrorHandlingClass errorHandling = new ErrorHandlingClass();

        AsseblymRefClass assemblyRef = new AsseblymRefClass();

        assemblyRef.DoStuff(errorHandling.HandleErrorsFromOtherClass);
    }
```

Any method that fits the delegate can be used. Thus, you can replace your production code, with something that doesn't show a messagebox when unit testing.

Comment: That's an interesting thought.  That may actually help be the best of both worlds.